# How to permanently delete a specific entry from Vim's command-line history without losing the changelists of the recently edited files?

Tags: vim

When we execute a Vim Ex command, it gets saved in the command-line history, which we can access by opening the command-line window with `q:`.

However, sometimes, I want to be able to remove some of them permanently. For example, if I execute the command `:a`, all subsequent commands in the command-line window are recognized as elements of the syntax group `vimInsert`, which is linked to the highlight group `String`, which is colored in cyan in my colorscheme.

To fix the syntax highlighting, I could try to delete the `:a` command from the command-line window hitting `dd`, but the entry is removed only while the window is opened. As soon as I close it, and reopen it later, the `:a` command is back. To make the removal permanent, I tried to add an autocmd in my `vimrc`:

```
augroup my_cmdline_window
    au!
    au CmdWinLeave * call s:update_history()
augroup END

fu! s:update_history() abort
    let new_hist = getline(1, '$')
    call histdel(':')
    for i in new_hist
        call histadd(':', i)
    endfor
endfu
```

It calls a function, which updates the command history by reading it from the current window, before closing it. It works while the current Vim session is running, but as soon as I quit it then start a new one, all the deleted entries are back.

I think the reason why the removal doesn't persist across sessions, is because when I quit a session Vim merges the current command-line history with the one stored in `~/.viminfo`.

What is saved inside this file is controlled by the `'viminfo'` option. The value of my `'viminfo'` is:

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
```

It doesn't contain the `:` parameter, which sets the maximum number of items in the command-line history, which are to be saved. It means that Vim should use the `'history'` option. The default value of my `'history'` is `1000`.

So, to force Vim to overwrite the command-line history stored inside `~/.viminfo` with the one of the current session, I tried to use the `:wviminfo` command inside my autocmd:

```
augroup my_cmdline_window
    au!
    au CmdWinLeave * call s:update_history()
augroup END

fu! s:update_history() abort
    let new_hist = getline(1, '$')
    call histdel(':')
    for i in new_hist
        call histadd(':', i)
    endfor
    wviminfo!
endfu
```

I added a bang to `:wviminfo`, which according to `:h :wviminfo`:

```
When [!] is used, the old information is not read first,
only the internal info is written.
```

It seems to work, because with this autocmd, the removal of an entry inside the command-line window persists across sessions. However, it also seems to erase all the changelists of the recently edited files, because after starting a new Vim session, all their changelists are empty.

And since `:h 'viminfo` explains that when you include the `'` item in `'viminfo'`, the changelist and the jumplist are also stored in `~/.viminfo`, I suspect that the jumplist and the marks are also lost after using `:wviminfo!`.

Is there a way to avoid the loss of the changelists/jumplists/marks, while still removing an arbitrary entry from the command-line history?

---

Edit:

I came up with this:

```
augroup my_cmdline_window
    au!
    au CmdWinEnter * let s:old_cmdline_hist = getline(1, line('$')-1)
    au CmdWinLeave * call s:update_history()
augroup END

fu! s:update_history() abort
    let hist = filter(getline(1, '$'), 'v:val !~# "^\\s*$"')

    call histdel(':')
    for i in hist
        call histadd(':', i)
    endfor

    let viminfo = expand('~/.viminfo')
    if !filereadable(viminfo)
        return
    endif

    let info = readfile(viminfo)
    let deleted_entries = filter(copy(s:old_cmdline_hist), 'index(hist, v:val) == -1')

    call map(deleted_entries, 'index(info, ":".v:val)')
    call sort(filter(deleted_entries, 'v:val >= 0'))
    if empty(deleted_entries)
        return
    endif

    for entry in reverse(deleted_entries)
        call remove(info, entry, entry + 1)
    endfor
    call writefile(info, viminfo, 'b')
endfu
```

Here's what the code does:

When you enter the command-line window, the 1st autocmd captures the command-line history inside `s:old_cmdline_hist`.

When you leave it, the 2nd autocmd updates the history of the current session, and tries to remove the deleted entries from `~/.viminfo`.

```
let hist = filter(getline(1, '$'), 'v:val !~# "^\\s*$"')
call histdel(':')
for i in hist
    call histadd(':', i)
endfor
```

This block updates only the history of the current session.

```
let viminfo = expand('~/.viminfo')
if !filereadable(viminfo)
    return
endif
```

This one checks whether `~/.viminfo` is readable. If it's not, the function stops.

```
let info = readfile(viminfo)
let deleted_entries = filter(copy(s:old_cmdline_hist), 'index(hist, v:val) == -1')
```

This block gets the contents of `~/.viminfo` inside the list `info` (1 item = 1 line). It also gets the entries which were deleted by invoking `filter()`. The latter removes all the entries which don't satisfy the condition `index(hist, v:val) == -1`. This expression is true if an entry of the old history, on which `filter()` operates, is not inside the new history.

```
call map(deleted_entries, 'index(info, ":".v:val)')
```

This line converts the deleted text entries into their line addresses inside `~/.viminfo`.

```
call sort(filter(deleted_entries, 'v:val >= 0'))
if empty(deleted_entries)
    return
endif
```

This block sorts the line addresses, and removes the ones which are not positive, in case some of them weren't found in the previous step (`index()` returned `-1`). It also checks whether there are still line addresses at this point, and if there aren't, again, the function stops.

```
for entry in reverse(deleted_entries)
    call remove(info, entry, entry + 1)
endfor
```

This block removes the relevant lines from `info`. It deletes 2 lines (`entry` and `entry + 1`), because for every command-line saved in `~/.viminfo`, there's also a 2nd line which seems to be a timestamp. Also, it deletes in reverse order, to not have to update the addresses of the lines to delete (every time you delete a line, the addresses of the next ones are decreased by one).

```
call writefile(info, viminfo, 'b')
```

This line overwrites `~/.viminfo` with the new contents, which should be the same as before, without the lines deleted in the command-line window.

I don't post it as an answer, as I'm not sure it's reliable and there aren't any side-effects. I did a backup of `~/.viminfo` before testing the code.

Edit2:

I don't think it's able to delete a line which contains a literal carriage return. There may be other special characters causing a similar issue (like a null character `^@`).

Answer (score 3):

History is stored in `.viminfo` file in plain text. So you could just open your `.viminfo` and delete that buggy line.

Alternatively, You can clear the history via the histdel() function, e.g. for searches:

`:call histdel('/')`

You can delete certain history entries by number or regex. See `:help histdel`.